# global mvc filter or httpmodule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httpmodule

I am currently working on an MVC4 application. I have a web forms background and this is my first MVC4 app.

On the request for each page, I need to fire an action which places some items in the httpcontext that is reused in further processing. Normally with web forms I would use a http module for this, and perform the task on the beginning of the request of module. Or sometimes, I would have actions that need to be fired at PostAcquireRequestState etc.

But now I am working with MVC, is the better practice to create a global filter that gets fired during each controller action? Within the filter, I would place the same logic I would have in the httpmodule. What are the pros and cons to this approach?

Comment: You can go for either. It is difficult to give a suggestion unless you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For example I went to set up some cookies, insert items in to httpcontext and set the thread culture etc.

Answer (score 0):

Filters are executed later in MVC request processing pipeline. For stuff like setting culture I would recommend to do that as earlier as possible like in the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event.

I guess model binding happens earlier than filters and because of that you will face some culture related issues http://gedgei.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/asp-net-mvc-localization-using-actionfilter/. I would vote to go for custom `HttpModule` over filters in this case.

http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/smedina/2008/12/17/internationalization-in-aspnet-mvc/